# bundler: failed to load command: puma

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, puma

Im trying to run the heroku local command in CML `heroku local`. `heroku local` command allows you to boot the project locally in the same way that it will be once it's pushed to Heroku to troubleshoot problems in a local development environment. Ive tried deleting my Gemfile.lock and running bundle install again did not work. I also tried using command `bundle exec heroku local` and I'm still getting the same error message.

I installed ruby using home-brew through the CML. Output of `ruby-v`: `ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin21]`. Output of `file $(which ruby)`: `Users/chris/.rubies/ruby-2.7.6/bin/ruby: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64.`

My GemFile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.7.6"
gem "sinatra", "~>1.4.7"
gem "sinatra-contrib"
gem "erubis"

group :production do
  gem "puma"
end
```

My Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    backports (3.23.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    puma (6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (1.6.13)
    rack-protection (1.5.5)
      rack
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    sinatra (1.4.8)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sinatra-contrib (1.4.7)
      backports (>= 2.0)
      multi_json
      rack-protection
      rack-test
      sinatra (~> 1.4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    tilt (2.0.11)

PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-21

DEPENDENCIES
  erubis
  puma
  sinatra (~> 1.4.7)
  sinatra-contrib

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.6p219

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.26
```

Expected return value:

```
$ heroku local
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
web.1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Actual return value:

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/bin/puma)
4:29:41 PM web.1 |  /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma.rb:14:in `require': dlopen(/Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0
4:29:41 PM web.1 |  >  /lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle (LoadError)
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:6:in `require_relative'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/bin/puma:6:in `require'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/puma-6.0.0/bin/puma:6:in `<top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/bin/puma:25:in `load'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/bin/puma:25:in `<top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli.rb:486:in `exec'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/gems/bundler-2.3.26/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
4:29:41 PM web.1 |      from /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/2.7.6/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
4:29:41 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

Ive tried deleting my Gemfile.lock and running bundle install again did not work. I also tried using command `bundle exec heroku local` and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? Also, please run `ruby -v` and add it to your question, then run `file $(which ruby)` and add it to your question, then run `which ruby` and add it to your question. The problem is that `bundle install` appears to be compiling the x86_64 version of Puma but your Mac has an arm64 CPU. I don't know how `heroku local` works, it's possible that it's an x86_64 application and that it's forcing that platform, or perhaps your installed version of Ruby is forcing it.

Comment: @anothermh I installed ruby using home-brew through the CML. Output of `ruby-v`: ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin21]. Output of `file $(which ruby)`: Users/chris/.rubies/ruby-2.7.6/bin/ruby: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64.  `heroku local` command allows you to boot the project locally in the same way that it will be once it's pushed to Heroku to troubleshoot problems in a local development environment.

Comment: Look at spickermann's answer. They're correct. And for future reference, when asked for more detail add the detail into your post by editing it. Don't try to put info into comments like this.

Answer (score 4):

When running your application locally on Apple Silicon and on production on Heroku then that means you are running your application on different platforms. And you have to make Bundler aware that it needs to be able to handle the required gems for both platforms.

While Bundler's generic `ruby` platform works in most cases, there are edge cases in which working with the platform-specific versions is required or preferred. For example, installing the `libv8-node` gem is extremely slow on Apple Silicon when not using the correct platform. Another example seems to be the `puma` gem you are using that explicitly requires [the correct platform configuration to work](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2734).

Therefore, I suggest adding all platforms that you are currently using to the `Gemfile`. That ensures that you do not add gems that are not available for all platforms. And the ability to use platform-optimized versions should improve especially the compiling time of gems with C bindings.

I suggest adding all platforms you are using (according to the error message) to your Gemfile like this:

```
bundle lock --add-platform ruby x86_64 arm64
```

Then run `bundle install` again.

See the Bundler documentation about [`bundle platform`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-platform.1.html) and [`bundle lock`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-lock.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! So the problem was I was using x86_64 architecture but I needed to use arm64 architecture. I verified which architecture by using command `uname -m`. To switch to arm64 I used command `env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error (not using heroku) and solved it with `bundle install --force` which forces all gems to re-download and rebuild